# Formatting for zip function in Python 3.x (Error message:zip argument #1 must support iteration)

Tags: python-3.x

I am stuck on how to format my zip function. I am aware that zip function only takes iterable objects (lists, sets, tuples, strings, iterators, etc). So far, I am trying to generate an output file that zips three float values in all separate columns. I would really appreciate getting some feedback on how else I can tackle this problem while getting the same outcome.
Fyi, ny input file has something like this..

```
1600     1
1700     3
1800     2.5
3000     1
7000     5
```

The following is my code so far.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import csv

myfiles = os.listdir('input') 

for file in myfiles:
    size=[]
    norm_intensity=[]    
    with open('input/'+file, 'r') as f:
        data = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',') 
        next(data)
        next(data)
        for row in data:
            size.append(float(row[0]))
            norm_intensity.append(float(row[1]))

        x_and_y = []
        row = np.array([list (i) for i in zip(size,norm_intensity)])
        for x, y in row:
            if y>0:       
                x_and_y.append((x,y))

    """""""""""""""""
    Sum of intensity from the first pool
    """""""""""""""""            

    first_x=[]
    first_y= []
    for x,y in (x_and_y):
        if x>1600 and x<2035.549:
            first_x.append(x)
            first_y.append(y)

    first_sum=np.sum(first_y)
```

Up to this point, I am collecting y value when x is greater than 1600 but smaller than 2035.549
In a similar way, I get second sum and third sum (each has a different x range).

***The following is the most troubling part so far.***

```
first_pool=first_sum/(first_sum+second_sum+third_sum)
second_pool=second_sum/(first_sum+second_sum+third_sum)
third_pool=third_sum/(first_sum+second_sum+third_sum)

with open ('output_pool/'+file, 'w') as f:
    for a,b,c in zip(first_pool,second_pool,third_pool):        
        f.write('{0:f},{1:f},{2:f}\n'.format(a,b,c))
```

What I wanted to have at the end is the following..

```
first_pool     second_pool      third_pool
(first_sum)    (second_sum)     (third_sum)
```

Since first_pool, second_pool, third_pool are all floats, I am currently running to a message that is saying, `zip argument #1 must support iteration`. Do you have any suggestions that I could still achieve the goal?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can also use Numpy to do your filtering for you: `table = np.array(list(zip(size, norm_intensity))); np.sum(table[:,1][(1600 < table[:,0]) & (table[:,0] < 2035.549) & (table[:,1] > 0)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you don't need zip. Something like the following should do what you want:

```
sums = [first_sum, second_sum, third_sum]
pools = [first_pool, second_pool, third_pool]
...
for a,b,c in [pools, sums]:
    f.write('{0:f},{1:f},{2:f}\n'.format(a,b,c))
```

Zipping would be, for example, if you had these two lists and wanted pairs of sums and pools:

```
for pool, summation in zip(pools, sums):
    f.write('Pool: {}, Sum: {}'.format(pool, summation))
    # Pool: 0.5, Sum: 10
    # Pool: 0.3, Sum: 6
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was overcomplicating things. I made a list of the "pools" and used it. It works great!